# Why do these two codes(php/C#) not encrypt/decrytp the same way?

Tags: c#, php, encryption, aes

On a 7.1 php web site this function encrypt a string and I should decrypt it in a C# webservice but they do not product same encrypted/decrypted result. Is there any reason that the encrypt methods in php and c# do not encrypt the same way with same secret key and iv key ?...

In PHP the encrypted question is : l0zhGwbpC3aQLaEuQAgmqL3gdWBPKhqjX7/s5o/x2i6mPW74kSmsWMesweNHYfR1
while in C# it gives this result: cWI7Ovb44gDl3WZ/p86JLjFdmAFml92VmbrwZnQZH9z+RMfGPx6hp2e6cAnMRYIr

```
<?php



$question = "Quel est le nom de jeune fille de ma mère ?";

$encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
$secret_key = 'Hakei54?sqSe6R71!lmdlrmPks65ekcj';
$secret_iv = 'Ryfdhi.q546dmlfp';

$key1 = hash('sha256', $secret_key);
$key2 = substr($key1, 0, 32);
$iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);

$output1 = openssl_encrypt($question, $encrypt_method, $key2, 0, $iv);
$output2 = base64_encode($output1);


echo "<b>La question</b> : ".$question."<br> <b>La question cyrptée</b> : ".$output1;
echo "<br>";
echo "<b>La question crytée encodée</b> : ".$output2;
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<b>$Secret_key</b> : ".$secret_key."<br>";
echo "<b>$secret_iv</b> : ".$secret_iv."<br>";
echo "<br>";

echo "<b>[ hash('sha256', $secret_key); ]</b> : ".$key1."<br>";
echo "<b>[ $key = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_key), 0, 32); ]</b> : ".$key2."<br>";
echo "<b>[ hash('sha256', $secret_iv) ]</b> : ".hash('sha256', $secret_iv)."<br>";
echo "<b>[ $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16); ]</b> : ".$iv."<br>";
echo "<br>";

echo "<b>[ $output1 = openssl_encrypt($question, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv); ]</b> : ".$output1."<br>";
echo "<b>[ $output2 = base64_encode($output1); ]</b> : ".$output2."<br>";

echo "<br>";
echo "Le code utilisé :<br><br>";
echo "<pre>
        $question = 'Quel est le nom de jeune fille de ma mère ?';

        $encrypt_method = 'AES-256-CBC';
        $secret_key = 'Hakei54?sqSe6R71!lm';
        $secret_iv = 'Ryfdhi.q546';

        $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);
        $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);

        $output1 = openssl_encrypt($question, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
        $output2 = base64_encode($output1);
</pre>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "La fonction php de décryptage :<br><br>";
echo "<pre>
        $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($question), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
</pre>";
```

?>

and C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string EncryptString(string plainText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        // Instantiate a new Aes object to perform string symmetric encryption
        Aes encryptor = Aes.Create();

        encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        // Set key and IV
        byte[] aesKey = new byte[32];
        Array.Copy(key, 0, aesKey, 0, 32);
        encryptor.Key = aesKey;
        encryptor.IV = iv;

        // Instantiate a new MemoryStream object to contain the encrypted bytes
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        // Instantiate a new encryptor from our Aes object
        ICryptoTransform aesEncryptor = encryptor.CreateEncryptor();

        // Instantiate a new CryptoStream object to process the data and write it to the 
        // memory stream
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aesEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        // Convert the plainText string into a byte array
        byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainText);

        // Encrypt the input plaintext string
        cryptoStream.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);

        // Complete the encryption process
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        // Convert the encrypted data from a MemoryStream to a byte array
        byte[] cipherBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

        // Close both the MemoryStream and the CryptoStream
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();

            // Convert the encrypted byte array to a base64 encoded string
            string cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);

        // Return the encrypted data as a string
        return cipherText;
    }

        static string DecryptString(string cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        // Instantiate a new Aes object to perform string symmetric encryption
        Aes encryptor = Aes.Create();

        encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        // Set key and IV
        byte[] aesKey = new byte[32];
        Array.Copy(key, 0, aesKey, 0, 32);
        encryptor.Key = aesKey;
        encryptor.IV = iv;

        // Instantiate a new MemoryStream object to contain the encrypted bytes
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        // Instantiate a new encryptor from our Aes object
        ICryptoTransform aesDecryptor = encryptor.CreateDecryptor();

        // Instantiate a new CryptoStream object to process the data and write it to the 
        // memory stream
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aesDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        // Will contain decrypted plaintext
        string plainText = String.Empty;

        try
        {
            // Convert the ciphertext string into a byte array
            byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

            // Decrypt the input ciphertext string
            cryptoStream.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);

            // Complete the decryption process
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            // Convert the decrypted data from a MemoryStream to a byte array
            byte[] plainBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

            // Convert the decrypted byte array to string
            plainText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close both the MemoryStream and the CryptoStream
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
        }

        // Return the decrypted data as a string
        return plainText;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string message = "Quel est le nom de jeune fille de ma mère ?";
            string password = "Hakei54?sqSe6R71!lmdlrmPks65ekcj";
            string secretiv= "Ryfdhi.q546dmlfp";

            // Create sha256 hash
            SHA256 mySHA256 = SHA256.Create();
            byte[] key = mySHA256.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password));
            byte[] iv = new byte[16] { 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 };
            Array.Copy(mySHA256.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretiv)), 0, iv, 0, 16);


            // Create secret IV
            //Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            string encrypted = EncryptString(message, key, iv);
            string decrypted = DecryptString(encrypted, key, iv);

            Console.WriteLine(encrypted);
            Console.WriteLine(decrypted);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not using the same key in PHP and C#; in PHP you throw away half of the hash. You shouldn't be using SHA anyway. Use [a proper key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Key_derivation_functions) instead. Also, IVs are not secret and [*must* be unpredictable in CBC mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3883/why-is-cbc-with-predictable-iv-considered-insecure)!

Comment: The plaintext contains non-ASCII characters, therefore UTF8 must be used instead of ASCII in C# code. In the PHP code, the digest must be returned binary and not hexadecimal encoded, so that the results match (third parameter of `hash` must be explicitly set to `true`).

Comment: @Peter : dun get you, in both code the secret code is the first 32 characters of the hashed string and the iv is only the first 16 characters of the hashed string....

Comment: No, in PHP the key is the first 32 bytes of the *hexadecimal encoding* of the hash, which is really only 16 bytes (stretched to double the size, so to say). Think about why it's called SHA-256. If you're throwing anything of the output away you *must* be left with less than 256 bits. That's all moot, though, because as I said you shouldn't be using SHA for key derivation in the first place.

Comment: @Peter. Ok think i get you now on the hexa/binary hash problem we will look at it, and first work with a pure ASCII string to avoir ASCII->UTF8 conversion.